# Regiones de Memoria de la JVM ¿Cual es la diferencia entra la Heap y Stack memory?

Tags: java

Cuando se arranca una aplicación java se puede setear las directivas de arranque de memoria con -Xms y Xmx para definir con que memoria mínima arranca la aplicación y cual es la máxima que podrá ocupar. 
Mi  consulta es ¿Que tipo de memoria se afecta con estos parámetros(-Xms , -Xmx) la Heap memory o la stack Memory  ?

De antemano gracias por la atención brindada.

Answer (score 4):

Editado: Mi respuesta original fue incorrecta.

Los argumentos -Xms y -Xmx solo afectan a la heap memoria, pero ambos estan incluidos en la memoria JVM.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Weston por tu colaboración, si afectan en ambos , comparto un video que explica este tema un poco mas a detalle https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vbnkZ7-25s

Comment: Lo siento. No leí la pregunta correctamente. He arreglado mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte , el grafico es muy explicativo , aqui comparto un enlace que aclara el concepto de la memoria PermGen : https://amunizmartin.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/memoria-permgen-en-java/

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendo que el comando -Xmx especifica la memoria maxima que la JVM tomara en cuenta para si, mientras que con -Xms le dices, cuando arranque, con cuanta memoria iniciara.

Supongo que la -Xmx hace referencia a la Stack Memory y -Xms a la Heap.

Lo acabo de leer de aqui:
http://www.javahispano.org/certificacion/2011/9/27/stack-y-heap.html

Comment: gracias por la información